# PHP File handling: Remove characters

Tags: php, file, character

I have a PHP function that reads the contents of a file given its path and removes first characters until it finds a '#' (first correct character in my file).This function works fine but how do I reduce the execution time ?

Please suggest/advice.

```
function foo($filepath)
{
    if(($contents = file_get_contents($filepath)) !== false)
    {
        while ($contents[0] != '#')
            $contents = substr($contents, 1);

        file_put_contents($filepath, $contents);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a problem - the code works. The post should go to codereview site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on codereview.

Comment: @suspectus One doesn't have to have a problem to ask here. Or, performance and efficiency *can* be a legitimate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be optimised in two ways: speed and memory management. You reading the entire file into memory is quite expensive and may fail entirely on large files. Instead, this'll be more memory efficient, but requires a second temporary file:

```
$fh = fopen($filepath, 'r');

do {
    $chr = fread($fh, 1);
} while ($chr != '#' && !feof($fh));

fseek($fh, -1, SEEK_CUR);

$temppath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'substr');
$tempfh   = fopen($temppath, 'w');

stream_copy_to_stream($fh, $tempfh);

fclose($fh);
fclose($tempfh);
rename($temppath, $filepath);
```

Speed-wise your existing solution can be simplified to:

```
if (($contents = file_get_contents($filepath)) !== false) {
    $index = strpos($contents, '#');
    file_put_contents($filepath, substr($contents, $index));
}
```

But again, it's reading everything into memory, which may be an important bottleneck to begin with.

Comment: Well, yes, I agree about - this is the _only_ way for big files to be processed. However, if file is big enough - then I doubt that __disk__ I/O will be faster than _memory_ routines

Comment: The data has to be read into memory either way. Disk I/O is the limiting factor in either case.

Comment: Not sure I've got the point. I mean - ok, let it be case when we can't read entire file. Then - we'll deal with disk I/O which is slow. However, if code will always work via copying file, then it will loose performance on small files. Hm. May be add size check and then combine advantages of both ways?

Comment: Hmm, not sure it would really lose performance on small files. Maybe if it has to read really far into the file before it finds the `#`. Apart from that, I'd think the stream copy function is tons more efficient than reading a file into PHP memory and putting it back. The final `rename` is minuscule file system meta overhead, it doesn't actually copy any data if that's what you mean. And you need to write the entire file anew either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo($filepath)
{
    if(($contents = file_get_contents($filepath)) !== false)
    {

      $contentExplode = explode("#",$contents );
      array_shift($contentExplode);//remove chars to the first #
      $contents = implode("#",$contentExplode);


      file_put_contents($filepath, $contents);
    }
    return false;
}
```